# sum values from preceding rows based on condition R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr, transform

I am trying to create a new column "sum_heat_on_prev_periods" which sums the values from the previous rows of a *different* column ONLY when a condition based on *third* different column is met.

To illuminate - I have timeseries data in dataframe hh02. Each row is a 30-minute period. When the heat turns off for the last time each day heat_final_off_algo3 == 1. I want to create a new column that returns a sum of how many periods the heat was *on* before that final turn-off. I only want to look back 8 hours for this sum so 16 rows (30-min each row). Each period that the heat is on is indicated by heat_on_prev == 1. If heat_final_off_algo3==0, which is the case for most rows, then the summation does not have to be done and the new column "sum_heat_on_prev_periods" would return NA.

My dataset is 20K+ rows but below is a sample with the necessary columns:

```
hh02 <- data.frame(row=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,11,13,14,15,16),
                 heat_final_off_algo3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 avg_roomtemp = c(20,19,19,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5),
                 temp_prev=c(21,20,19,19,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6),
                 heat_on_prev = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))

#heat_final_off_algo3 is a binary column with either 1 or 0 values indicating yes (1) algo is true or (0) algo is false 
  
#avg_roomtemp is average room temperature

#temp_prev is the room temperature from the previous row - created using lag(avg_roomtemp,1) 

#heat_on_prev is a binary column with either 1 or 0 values indicating yes (1) the heat was on in the previous period or no (0) heat was not on in the previous period
```

I want to create a new column "sum_heat_on_prev_periods" adds the "heat_on_prev" values from the immediate previous **16 rows** - but this will only be done for cases when heat_final_off_algo3 == 1, else (heat_final_off_algo3==0), I would like the "sum_heat_on_prev" column to return "NA"

Essentially "sum_heat_on_prev_periods" will be a total count of the 30-minutes periods in the previous 16 periods where the heat is on

The result/output would look something like this:

| row | heat_final_off_algo3 | avg_roomtemp | temp_prev | heat_on_prev | sum_heat_on_prev_periods |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 20 | 21 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 0 | 19 | 20 | 1 | NA |
| 3 | 1 | 19 | 19 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 17 | 19 | 0 | NA |
| 5 | 0 | 16 | 17 | 0 | NA |
| 6 | 0 | 15 | 16 | 0 | NA |
| 7 | 0 | 14 | 15 | 0 | NA |
| 8 | 0 | 13 | 14 | 1 | NA |
| 9 | 0 | 12 | 13 | 0 | NA |
| 10 | 1 | 11 | 12 | 0 | 4 |
| 11 | 0 | 10 | 11 | 0 | NA |
| 12 | 0 | 9 | 10 | 0 | NA |
| 13 | 0 | 8 | 9 | 1 | NA |
| 14 | 0 | 7 | 8 | 0 | NA |
| 15 | 0 | 6 | 7 | 0 | NA |
| 16 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 0 | NA |

To do this I attempted to write the function

```
fxn <- function(x) { 
  if (heat_final_off_algo3==1){
    sum_heat_on_prev_periods <- (heat_on_prev) + (lag(heat_on_prev,1)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,2)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,3)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,4)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,5)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,6)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,7)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,8)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,9)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,10)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,11)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,12)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,13)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,14)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,15)) + (lag(heat_on_prev,16))
  }
}
```

And tried to apply it using

```
hh02$sum_heat_on_prev_periods <- plyr::ddply(hh02, c("heat_final_off_algo3", "heat_on_prev"), fxn)
```

I have tried several variations of this-  even using mutate_if and case_when, but the above code/method was the closest I got for the code to run all the way through. However, it still does not work and returns the error "Error in .fun(piece, ...) : object 'heat_final_off_algo3' not found" - likely a misplaced error that is really in the code not in the object

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Your data has only 16 rows. What would happen if you change the condition from 16 to 10 for example? How would the result look like?

Comment: Your sample `data.frame` is broken: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 16`, I suggest replacing it with `hh02<-structure(list(row=1:16,heat_final_off_algo3=c(0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L),avg_roomtemp=c(20L,19L,19L,17L,16L,15L,14L,13L,12L,11L,10L,9L,8L,7L,6L,5L),temp_prev=c(21L,20L,19L,19L,17L,16L,15L,14L,13L,12L,11L,10L,9L,8L,7L,6L),heat_on_prev=c(1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,-16L))` (taken from the formatted table)

Comment: @onyambu this is a small portion of my data - the true data frame has 20k+ rows i showed 16 here as an example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a "period" is one row, we can use `zoo::rollapply` for this:

```r
hh02 %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = if_else(
      heat_final_off_algo3 > 0,
      zoo::rollapplyr(heat_on_prev, 16, partial = TRUE, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
      heat_on_prev[NA])
  )
#    row heat_final_off_algo3 avg_roomtemp temp_prev heat_on_prev sum_heat_on_prev_periods newcol
# 1    1                    0           20        21            1                       NA     NA
# 2    2                    0           19        20            1                       NA     NA
# 3    3                    1           19        19            1                        3      3
# 4    4                    0           17        19            0                       NA     NA
# 5    5                    0           16        17            0                       NA     NA
# 6    6                    0           15        16            0                       NA     NA
# 7    7                    0           14        15            0                       NA     NA
# 8    8                    0           13        14            1                       NA     NA
# 9    9                    0           12        13            0                       NA     NA
# 10  10                    1           11        12            0                        4      4
# 11  11                    0           10        11            0                       NA     NA
# 12  12                    0            9        10            0                       NA     NA
# 13  13                    0            8         9            1                       NA     NA
# 14  14                    0            7         8            0                       NA     NA
# 15  15                    0            6         7            0                       NA     NA
# 16  16                    0            5         6            0                       NA     NA
```

The use of `heat_on_prev[NA]` is a way to ensure that we return the proper class of `NA` per the data. It's integer here, so we can use `NA_integer_`, but I prefer to keep the class guaranteed even if it (even-accidentally) shifts to `numeric`.

---

Data

```r
hh02 <- structure(list(row=1:16,heat_final_off_algo3=c(0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L),avg_roomtemp=c(20L,19L,19L,17L,16L,15L,14L,13L,12L,11L,10L,9L,8L,7L,6L,5L),temp_prev=c(21L,20L,19L,19L,17L,16L,15L,14L,13L,12L,11L,10L,9L,8L,7L,6L),heat_on_prev=c(1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,-16L))
```

Comment: for some reason every time I try to run this the newcol is not created in my dataframe. any idea why this could be happening? thank you very much for your thoughtful answer. @r2evans

Comment: i figured it out! for some reason my code needed to assign the code you provided to h02 first - so it looked like h02 <- h02%>% ....[your code]. THANK YOU!